# Fill circle with gradient

Tags: c++, opencv

I want fill circle with gradient color, like I show on bottom. I can't figure out easy way, how to do that.
I can make more circles, but transitions are visible.

```
cv::circle(img, center, circle_radius * 1.5, cv::Scalar(1.0, 1.0, 0.3), CV_FILLED);
cv::circle(img, center, circle_radius * 1.2, cv::Scalar(1.0, 1.0, 0.6), CV_FILLED);
cv::circle(img, center, circle_radius, cv::Scalar(1.0, 1.0, 1.0), CV_FILLED);
```

[image]

Comment: Presumably you can just set the luma/greyscale value as a function of distance from the centre?

Comment: @EdChum Yes. Depends of distance from center.

Comment: Yes, and @EdChum is saying just create a function which calculates a distance from the center and then assign it a value based on that distance.

Comment: But then I need create more circles?

Comment: No, you don't *need* to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you need to do is create a function which takes in a central point and a new point, calculates the distance, and returns a grayscale value for that point. Alternatively you could just return the distance, store the *distance* at that point, and then scale the whole thing later with `cv::normalize()`.

So let's say you have the central point as `(50, 50)` in a `(100, 100)` image. Here's pseudocode for what you'd want to do:

```
function euclideanDistance(center, point)  # returns a float
    return sqrt( (center.x - point.x)^2 + (center.y - point.y)^2 )

center = (50, 50)
rows = 100
cols = 100

gradient = new Mat(rows, cols) # should be of type float

for row < rows:
    for col < cols:
        point = (col, row)
        gradient[row, col] = euclideanDistance(center, point)

normalize(gradient, 0, 255, NORM_MINMAX, uint8)
gradient = 255 - gradient
```

Note the steps here:

1. Create the Euclidean distance function to calculate distance
2. Create a floating point matrix to hold the distance values
3. Loop through all rows and columns and assign a distance value
4. Normalize to the range you want (you could stick with a float here instead of casting to `uint8`, but you do you)
5. Flip the binary gradient, since distances farther away will be brighter---but you want the opposite.

Now for your exact example image, there's a gradient in a circle, whereas this method just creates the whole image as a gradient. In your case, if you want a specific radius, just modify the function which calculates the Euclidean distance, and if it's beyond some distance, set it to 0 (the value at the center of the circle, which will be flipped eventually to white):

```
function euclideanDistance(center, point, radius)  # returns a float
    distance = sqrt( (center.x - point.x)^2 + (center.y - point.y)^2 )
    if distance > radius:
        return 0
    else
        return distance
```

---

Here is the above in actual C++ code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <cmath>

float euclidean_distance(cv::Point center, cv::Point point, int radius){
    float distance = std::sqrt(
        std::pow(center.x - point.x, 2) + std::pow(center.y - point.y, 2));
    if (distance > radius) return 0;
    return distance;
}

int main(){

    int h = 400;
    int w = 400;
    int radius = 100;
    cv::Mat gradient = cv::Mat::zeros(h, w, CV_32F);

    cv::Point center(150, 200);
    cv::Point point;

    for(int row=0; row<h; ++row){
        for(int col=0; col<w; ++col){
            point.x = col;
            point.y = row;
            gradient.at<float>(row, col) = euclidean_distance(center, point, radius);
        }
    }

    cv::normalize(gradient, gradient, 0, 255, cv::NORM_MINMAX, CV_8U);
    cv::bitwise_not(gradient, gradient);

    cv::imshow("gradient", gradient);
    cv::waitKey();

}
```

[image: Gradient image]

---

A completely different method (though doing the same thing) would be to use the [`distanceTransform()`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#distancetransform). This function maps the distance from the center of a white blob to the nearest black value to a grayscale value, like we were doing above. This code is more concise and does the same thing. However, it can work on arbitrary shapes, not just circles, so that's cool.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

int main(){

    int h = 400;
    int w = 400;
    int radius = 100;
    cv::Point center(150, 200);
    cv::Mat gradient = cv::Mat::zeros(h, w, CV_8U);
    cv::rectangle(gradient, cv::Point(115, 100), cv::Point(270, 350), cv::Scalar(255), -1, 8 );

    cv::Mat gradient_padding;
    cv::bitwise_not(gradient, gradient_padding);

    cv::distanceTransform(gradient, gradient, CV_DIST_L2, CV_DIST_MASK_PRECISE);
    cv::normalize(gradient, gradient, 0, 255, cv::NORM_MINMAX, CV_8U);

    cv::bitwise_or(gradient, gradient_padding, gradient);

    cv::imshow("gradient-distxform.png", gradient);
    cv::waitKey();

}
```

[image: Gradient from distance transform]

Comment: I think that solution with drawing many circles will be easier to implement

Comment: @KamilSzelag I'm not sure I agree but your method works totally fine too. The difference is that your method will discretize the grayscale values by which radius each pixel is closest to, mine will get assigned unique values for each separate distance. In other words your gradient image will have `radius` distinct grayscale vals, mine will have the number of distinct distances grayscale vals. Could make a difference for large radii. I wonder which is faster though?

Comment: Unique values in each pixel equals better quality, true. I wonder if it is noticeable change on raster image. I think, that your method is faster.

Comment: @KamilSzelag "I wonder if it is noticeable change on raster image." Probably not, which is why I think your method would work fine for basically any use-case too. You would see a difference in thresholding; yours would return the same circles you drew with, mine won't return the same circles as yours (unless the threshold value was the same as a value at an integer distance away from the center). Either way they'd both return circle-like things, just not necessarily the same circle that OpenCV would draw.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds pseudo-code is very good. But in C++ have problems  with implementation. Specifically with assign a distance value. If you can put C++ example will be very nice. Your solution probably work faster then Kamil's.

Comment: @NejcGalof sure, I added the C++ code. For future reference, if you do try to implement a solution, edit your original question to add the code. That way I might be able to just give a simple hint to solve your problem, or can copy/paste your code and not have to write it all from scratch. Not a big deal here but, for the future... :)

Comment: @NejcGalof I added another completely different method to do this which is really nice and clean using OpenCV's `distanceTransform()` function, which does roughly the same thing as above. It finds white blobs (via connected components), finds the centers of those blobs, and then computes the distance to the nearest black pixel for every pixel inside the blob. This is cool because it can work on arbitrary shapes. If you draw a white circle on a black image, it's identical to the previous version I showed. But you can do this with ellipses, boxes, *any* shape white blob!

Answer (score 5):

You have to draw many circles. Color of each circle depends on distance from center. Here is some simple example:

```
void printGradient(cv::Mat &_input,const cv::Point &_center, const double radius)
{
   cv::circle(_input, _center, radius, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0), -1);

   for(double i=1; i<radius; i=i++)
   {
       const int color = 255-int(i/radius * 255); //or some another color calculation
       cv::circle(_input,_center,i,cv::Scalar(color, color, color),2);
   }  
}
```

And result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another approach not mentioned yet is to precompute a circle gradient image (with one of the mentioned approaches like the accepted solution) and use affine warping with linear interpolation to create other such circles (different sizes). This can be faster, if warping and interpolation are optimized and maybe accelerated by hardware.
Result might be a bit worse than perfect.

I once used this to create a single individual vignetting mask circle for each frame innendoscopic imaging. Was faster than to compute the distances "manually".